# How to access home computer with dynamic IP?

Tags: dns

My friend want to access cctv connected to his computer.

However, his computer has dynamic IP.

I supposes he wants a domain name to point to that dynamic IP.

How to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many dynamic dns services on the internet. Some are free and some are payed, I run my own website and use ZoneEdit, which works great for my needs and only costs $1 per month! However, there are also free ones such as that run by hurricane electric and noip

Comment: how does that dns know your IP address?

Comment: You setup a dynamic dns client on your computer (or router if it supports it). The actual one you use depends on the OS

Comment: Just to further clarify, the client running on your computer will check to see if your IP has changed then report back to whatever service provider you choose and they will update the dns record on their servers. Also [here is a good list of providers](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/). Personally I use No-IP.com, so I can use MyCustomName.no-ip.com will always point to my current IP address at no cost. If you own your own domain name (ie: MyCusomName.com) choose one of the providers that offer free domains, not just subdomains.